# Binomial Distribution for defects

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> A batch of components has arrived at a distributor.
>       The batch can be characterized only if the proportion of defective components is at most 0.10.
>
> The distributor decides to randomly select 10 components and to accept the batch only if the number of defective components in the sample is at most 2.
>
> a. What is the probability that the batch will be accepted when the actual proportion of defectives is 0.01? 0.05? 0.10? 0.20?
>
> b. Let $p$ denote the actual proportion of the defectives in the batch.
>          A graph of P(batch is accepted) as a function of $p$, with $p$ on the horizontal axis and $P($batch is accepted$)$ on the vertical axis, is called the operating characteristic curve for the acceptance sampling plan.
>
> Use the results of part (a) to sketch this curve for $0 \le p \le 1$.
>
> c. Repeat parts (a) and (b) with "1" replacing "2" in the acceptance sampling plan.
>
> d. Which of the two sampling plans, that of part (a), (c), appears most satisfactory and why?

I've got the following at the moment for part a but I get the feeling that I'm doing this slightly wrong and don't want to do all of it incorrectly.

a.) $n = 10$

$k($number of success$) = 2$

$p($population proportion$) = .01$

$P(k \le 2) = \binom{n}{k} \times p^k \times (1-p)^(n-k)$

$P(k \le 2) = .00441$

Also I'm unsure of what is being asked for part b.

Comment: Is asking you the graph of  $\binom{n}{k} \times p^k \times (1-p)^{n-k}$ for n=10 and k=2 and p between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is Binomial($n,p)$, then $P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. Thus, $P(X \leq k) = \sum_{l \leq k} \binom{n}{l} p^l (1-p)^{n-l}$. So, your formula for (a) is wrong.

Comment: what does the (n over k ) mean exactly?

Comment: Thats a binomial coefficient - its the number of ways you can choose k objects from n different objects (without regard to their order of choice).